# Predefined IBDesignable

Tags: ios, ibdesignable

I've been searching every possible way I can think off and haven't found a solution.

So I was wondering if there is a possibility if you can create list of values for IBDesignable variable and if so, how do you do it.
I'm looking for this because I don't like that the only values I can get are either a number, boolean selection or writable string.

I would like to have a few predefined values that I can select from, like lets say text type on UITextField.

EDIT1:

Can anyone tell me how to create IBInspectable of type range in swift, since:

```
@IBInspectable var test = 0...3 {
    didSet {
        // Ensure user enters a valid shape while making it lowercase.
        // Ignore input if not valid.
    }
}
```

doesn't work with error "Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C".

Comment: I don't think you can specify an enum type value for your `IBInspectable` value. Source & workarround (?) : https://medium.com/@GeraldoBastos/why-i-cant-use-ibinspectable-with-enumeration-ecd83ba6671a

Comment: Yes I figured out I cant create an enum, but is there a way to lets say have a drop down menu with numbers 1 and 2  or two strings?

Comment: Not at present. From Apple's docs, "You can add the IBInspectable attribute to any property in a class declaration, class extension, or category of type: boolean, integer or floating point number, string, localized string, rectangle, point, size, color, range, and nil.". See https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/10.1/#/devf60c1c514

Comment: Ok, but does anybody know if I can set it ti integer and limit it to only a few numbers, so that the user can only select a few options?